I am getting error Error 429 too many requests on createIngress in Livekit even when not making many requests
I'm working on integrating LiveKit's API to manage streams in my application, and I’ve run into an issue when attempting to create a new ingress. Every time I attempt to create an ingress with IngressClient.createIngress(), I receive the following error:
Error: Request failed with status 429: Too Many Requests
    at TwirpRpc.request (file://E%3A/codingfolder/pulseStream/pulsestream/node_modules/livekit-server-sdk/src/TwirpRPC.ts:51:12)

Thanks in advance!
Here’s a breakdown of the issue:
I am using the IngressClient.createIngress() method from the livekit-server-sdk.
I’ve been getting the error even after attempting retries with increasing delay.
The rate-limiting message keeps repeating without successfully creating the ingress.

import { IngressClient, IngressInput } from "livekit-server-sdk";

const IgClient = new IngressClient(
  process.env.LIVEKIT_API_URL,
  process.env.LIVEKIT_API_KEY,
  process.env.LIVEKIT_SECRET_KEY
);

async function createIngress(Ingresstype, id) {
  try {
    const options = {
      name: id,
      roomName: id,
      participantName: id,
      participantIdentity: id,
    };
    const ingress = await IgClient.createIngress(Ingresstype, options);
    return ingress;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating ingress:", error);
  }
}

What I’ve Tried:

I have confirmed that the API keys are correct.
I’ve tried adding retry logic with increasing delay (1s, 2s, 4s, etc.), but the error persists.
I’ve reviewed the LiveKit documentation and could not find a solution regarding rate limits.

My Question:
why I am getting error even I am not making many requests just one request as I am building it
Thanks

Contact their support channel.

Perhaps somebody else is using your API key. I'd start by generating a new one

Standard practice for 429 errors is to inspect the headers for additional information about the specific limit that has been exceeded and should also include a retry-after header so that you don't have to guess timeframe to wait.
LiveKit will also return 429 if you are hitting connection limits which are based on your subscription level
LiveKit's quotas are documented here: https://docs.livekit.io/home/cloud/quotas-and-limits/

You can view the current connection limits on your project at any time in the LiveKit Cloud dashboard by navigating to Settings and selecting the Project tab.

